# How to extract a set of isolated 2D arrays from a larger 2D array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing

Let's say I have a 2D array filled with a lot of blank spaces, but there are smaller isolated 2D arrays contained between these blanks.  For example:

```
var aVO = [
  ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7", "col8", "col9"],
  ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
  [1, 2, 3, "", "", "", "", "", ""],
  [4, 5, 6, "", "", "a", "b", "", ""],
  [7, 8, 9, "", "", "c", "d", "", 1],
  ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 2],
  ["", "", "z", "y", "", "", "", "", 3],
  ["", "x", "w", "v", "", 7, 7, 7, ""],
  ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
  ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
  ["", "A1", "B1", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
  ["", "A2", "B2", "C2", "", "", "HELLO", "", ""]
]
```

I'm interested in converting this into eight 2D arrays:

```
[["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7", "col8", "col9"]]
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
[["a","b"],["c","d"]]
[[1],[2],[3]]
[["", "z","y"],["x","w", "v"]]
[[7,7,7]]
[["A1","B1",""],["A2","B2","C2"]]
[["HELLO"]]
```

What's the best approach to extract these smaller 2D arrays?  I was thinking about iterating row-by-row but it's hard to visualize how to elegantly extract data like `[["", "z","y"],["x","w","v"]]` (note how "x" isn't directly below "z", and therefore the resulting 2D array needs to reflect that shift).  Thanks for any help!

Comment: The _logic_ by which you want to group those elements is pretty unclear, so please explain that properly first of all.

Comment: @CBroe The data contains "islands" of values, separated by empty strings. OP wants to extract those islands. The result should be a list of 2d-arrays of constant row size, which explains why the empty string in the `z y` row needs to be included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach using `Set` and `Map` instances to keep track of groups of cells:

- Create cells out of the 2d array
- Create an empty `Map` in which we will store for each cell with a value to which group it belongs
- Loop over each cell

  - If a cell is empty, go to the next one
  - If a cell has a value

    - Create a group for it. The group marks a top left and bottom right position and keeps track of a set of cells that belong to it.
    - Check which adjacent cells already belong to a group
    - Merge the newly created group with all of the groups found for adjacent cells
- Collect all unique groups from the `Map`
- For each unique group, slice out the part between its top left and bottom right corner from the initial grid

```js
const Cell = memo(
  (r, c) => ({ r, c }),
  ([r, c]) => `${r}_${c}`
);

Cell.neighbors = ({ r, c }) => [
  Cell(r, c + 1), // Right
  Cell(r + 1, c), // Down
  Cell(r, c - 1), // Left
  Cell(r - 1, c), // Up
];

// Create a single-cell group
const Group = (cell) => ({
  minR: cell.r,
  maxR: cell.r + 1,
  minC: cell.c,
  maxC: cell.c + 1,
  cells: new Set([cell])
});

// Merge two groups into a new one
Group.merge = (g1, g2) => ({
  minR: Math.min(g1.minR, g2.minR),
  maxR: Math.max(g1.maxR, g2.maxR),
  minC: Math.min(g1.minC, g2.minC),
  maxC: Math.max(g1.maxC, g2.maxC),
  cells: new Set([ ...g1.cells, ...g2.cells ])
});

// Take a grid and slice out the part covered by a group
Group.extractFromGrid = grid => ({ minR, maxR, minC, maxC }) => grid
  .slice(minR, maxR)
  .map(row => row.slice(minC, maxC));

// Create all cells with their values
const grid = getData();
const allCells = grid.flatMap(
  (row, ri) => row.map(
    (value, ci) => Cell(ri, ci)
  )
);

const groupPerCell = new Map();

allCells.forEach(current => {
  const inIsland = grid[current.r][current.c] !== "";
  if (inIsland) {  
    const newGroup = Cell
      .neighbors(current)
      .filter(c => groupPerCell.has(c))
      .map(c => groupPerCell.get(c))
      .reduce(Group.merge, Group(current));
   
    // Store a reference to the group for each member
    newGroup.cells.forEach(c => {
      groupPerCell.set(c, newGroup);
    });
  }  
});

const allGroups = [...new Set(groupPerCell.values())];
const allValues = allGroups.map(Group.extractFromGrid(grid));

console.log(allValues);



function memo(f, hash) {
  const cache = {};
  
  return (...args) => {
    const k = hash(args);
    if (!cache[k]) cache[k] = f(...args);
    
    return cache[k];
  }
}

function getData() { return [
  ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7", "col8", "col9"],
  ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
  [1, 2, 3, "", "", "", "", "", ""],
  [4, 5, 6, "", "", "a", "b", "", ""],
  [7, 8, 9, "", "", "c", "d", "", 1],
  ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 2],
  ["", "", "z", "y", "", "", "", "", 3],
  ["", "x", "w", "v", "", 7, 7, 7, ""],
  ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
  ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
  ["", "A1", "B1", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
  ["", "A2", "B2", "C2", "", "", "HELLO", "", ""]
]; }
```

Comment: This is such a brilliant and elegant solution, thank you so much for taking the time to write this and explain it.  Identifying the "neighboring" cells is definitely the way to go.  I keep going back to your solution to absorb it (I'm more of an ES5 developer than ES6, so I learned a lot from your answer).   Thanks again!!

Comment: This is the most amazing answer regarding JS I have ever seen!